# Show items of arrayList override toString() Android

Tags: java, android

**Original Question:**

I have a database where I have some items. It's my first time with android and databases. I have my connexion class, and another class where there is my method Select All.

In my ActivityMain I did an intent to call another activity overrided toString(just to train myself), at the moment where I clicked on a button. This button should in my Tree Class to show all my items of my method Select All an ArrayList.

Here the code in I returned my other Activity (ActivityDB) :

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
final DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(ActivityDB.this);
final TreeControl tr = new TreeControl(ActivityDB.this);

ArrayList<Tree> c = tr.getTreeWhere(null, null, db);


System.out.println("Retrieving items with loop using index and size list");
for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Index: " + i + " - Item: " + c.get(i));
}
```

My problem is, when NID because I click on the button, my system.out don't know how to return everything.println makes that : `Index: 0 - Item: com.iteso.pam_testjson.beans.Tree@42a7f188`

This is my IntentSo, how to call the other activity. The onclick() function is in the design code directly.

Here the intent return all items from my list and no only one :?

```
 public void newActivity(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityDB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here the design code :

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"
    android:id="@+id/buttonSelect"
    android:onClick="newActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

I don't understand what is wrong, if any of you can help me please my Tree definition :-)

Thank you by advance.

**Edited Question:**

I overrided toString() in my Tree Class to show all items of an ArrayList.
I returned my NID because I don't know how to return everything.
So, how to return all items from my list and no only one ?

Here my Tree definition :

```
public Tree() {
    NID = "";
    taxonomia = "";
    plantado = "";
    diametro = "";
    altura = "";
    valoracion = "";
    latitud = "";
    longitud = "";
    jardin = "";
    imagen = "";
}

public String toString() {
    return NID;
}
```

Comment: Where is your onClick() function??

Comment: You need to override `toString()` in `Tree`.

Comment: What do you think it should print?

Comment: Java's print method knows to fetch base types, such as string, float, integer... Java doesn't knows as it should print your object. You must "say" to java how to print it. When you call print on some object, internally it calls toString method of given object. So you need to override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your `get` methods from your `Tree` class (if you have any) or `Override` your `toString` method, on `Tree` class.

EDIT:

You may need to add (at least) some get methods to your `Tree` class and usually you'll need them.
This said, as [Alexander Ravikovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509169/alexander-ravikovich) said in the comments to your question:

> "Java's print method knows to fetch base types, such as string, float,
>   integer... Java doesn't knows as it should print your object. You must
>   "say" to java how to print it. When you call print on some object,
>   internally it calls toString method of given object. So you need to
>   override it."

So, let's say you add the get methods in your class and you define it this way (and assuming all variables are of type `String`):

```
public Tree() {
    NID = "";
    taxonomia = "";
    plantado = "";
    diametro = "";
    altura = "";
    valoracion = "";
    latitud = "";
    longitud = "";
    jardin = "";
    imagen = "";
}

public String getNid() {return NID;}
public String getTaxomia() {return taxomia;}
public String getPlantado() {return plantado;}
public String getDiametro() {return diametro;}
public String getAltura() {return altura;}
public String getValoracion() {return valoracion;}
public String getLatitud() {return latitud;}
public String getLongitud() {return longitud;}
public String getJardin() {return jardin;}
public String getImagen() {return imagen;}

@Override 
public String toString() {
    return "Nid: " + NID + " Taxomia: " + taxomia + " Plantado: " + plantado + " Diametro: " + diametro + " Altura: " + altura + " Valoracion: " + valoracion + " Latitud: " + latitud + " Longitud: " + longitud + " Jardin: " + " Imagen: " + imagen;
}
```

Then on your `for` cycle you can call the `get` method for the value(s) you may want to print. Lets say you want to prin the `NID`, `taxomia` and `Valoracion`. You can do it this way:

```
for(Tree tree : yourListName) {
   Log.d(TAG, "NID: " + tree.getNid() + " Taxomia: " + tree.getTaxomia() + " Valoracion: " + tree.getValoracion());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did that in my Tree class :     public String toString() {
        return NID;
    }. But how to show all datas and no only the NID ?

Comment: Then now if you run your code you should see the value that `NID` represents

Comment: Yes It showed that, and if I want to show all values, what should I return in the toString() method ?

Comment: Post your `Tree` definition (code) - edit your question and add it - and I'll explain it to you.

Comment: @maevy Just like `NID`, you have access to other variables of class Tree. Use them as required: `return "NID is: " + NID + " myOtherVariable is: " + myOtherVariable .... ;`. You can also include class instances using `myClassInstanceInTree.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is going as I want

Comment: @maevy Since this answers your question, consider accepting it by clicking the `checkmark` icon.